# How to install specific python version required by TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, command-line, operating-system

I have the following **operating system** :

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

`Python`  vertion: `Python 3.8.10`

I want to install spesfic `tensflow` vertion  --> `tensorflow=1.13.1,<1.14`
because it is in requierments file [HERE](https://github.com/Mohammed20201991/TextRecognitionDataGeneratorHuMu23/blob/master/requirements-hw.txt)
it seems that requierd old vertion of python like `python 3.6`

What Iam trying I am created venv with py and try to run the following command python3.6 -m venv "my_env_name"
bash: python3.6: command not found  in the meantime I am not able to write sudo on this remote server
What I expacted is to `downgrade python vertion` to be able to install requerments .

Answer (score 1):

your best approach might be to get conda either via Anaconda or Miniforge. at least for miniforge it is a user install not requiring root privilege (sudo). once you have conda you can create conda envs with the python version you need it will get downloaded automatically and active only in the created environment.